# Unable to remove previous employees from Azure DevOps Sprint Board Assignment drop-down

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, sprint

When attempting to assign someone to a bug or task on the Azure DevOps sprint board I can see a number of users that are no longer in my teams on DevOps or on the Azure ActiveDirectory in my organisation - yet I cannot find a way to remove them.

Is this list cached - it seems to show everyone who has ever worked for us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this list cached - it seems to show everyone who has ever worked for us?

The **Assigned To** and other Identity fields are supported by the **people picker feature**. Users that you've previously selected appear in the list automatically. If the organization is linked to AAD, people pickers provide support for searching all users and groups added to the AD, not just those added to the project. You can find more details in doc here：

[Identity fields, people-picker fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?view=azure-devops#identity-fields-people-picker-fields)

To remove the users from list:

1. make sure the user has been deleted from **both DevOps organization and AAD**.
2. Refresh the Brower page, try to assign the work item again to the deleted user, it will report error like `The identity value for  field "Assigned To" is an unknown identity', it will update people picker list backend.
   [image]
3. Refresh the page, check the "AssignTo" again, you cannot find the deleted user.

If you is still able to find the user, the user is still existing in your DevOps organization or AAD.

Comment: Hi @RNDThoughts, may i know if it works? let me know if you have queries.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks, shame it's not a little more obvious in the UI.

Comment: It worked for me too, but what is 'AAD'? And yes, there should be a betther way than to make the page show an error to force it to update the list.

Comment: AAD is Azure Active Directory, the account could be working account from AAD or MSA account.